# How to find if a function is inbuilt function or user-defined

Tags: javascript

Lets say if I have a function a. I would like to know if its inbuilt function or a function defined by the user. 
I have tried checking if a.toString() has `[native code]` in it but user-defined functions which have the substring `[native code]` would fail. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: _Custom_ Functions `toString()` cannot end with `[native code] }`, as otherwise the function(source) would be compiled due to syntax error.

Comment: Oh that makes sense..guess I should have thought about it a bit more
PS - I can accept it if post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here some code to check:

```
var rgx = /\[native code\]\s*\}\s*$/;

function some(){
    '[native code]'
}

console.log(
    rgx.test(print.toString()),
    rgx.test(some.toString())
);
```

Comment: I had used `some.toString().indexOf('[native code]', some.toString().length - '[native code]'.length) !== -1` to test it..using regex seems good too

Comment: Does your code work with inbuilt functions? As you looking at the end of  a stringified function. But it ends with `[native code] }`. And in IE there are newlines after `[native code] ` and `}`. And so the regexp also handles it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One, perhaps naive, approach would be to test whether the function name exists a property of the document:

```
function newFunction (){
    return true;
}

console.log('newFunction' in document, 'toString' in document);
```

This is, of course, *not* exhaustively tested and does fail if the function is created as an extension of a `prototype`, for example:

```
function newFunction (){
    return true;
}

Object.prototype.newFunctionName = function () {
    return 10 * 2;
};

console.log('newFunction' in document, 'toString' in document, 'newFunctionName' in document); // false, true, true
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PpL63/1/).

Given that it also fails for `'eval' in document` (in that it returns `false`), then this will, or *can*, only work to identify prototype-methods of the Objects. Which is, at best, an incomplete solution.

Comment: 'eval' in document returns false

Comment: Sadly, I'm embarrassed to confess that I have no better ideas... :(